# 2-way data binding not working in select tag in modal of Angular UI with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select

Here is Plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/CKcKLm?p=preview

After clicking "Open me" button, I am expecting it to do whatever I selected. It should always switch back to "white" option because

```
ng-change="refreshAmount()"
```

sets it back to:

```
$scope.myColor = $scope.colors[0];
```

As you can see in the logs, the `$scope.myColor` value is updated correctly (always outputs "white").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use object for the model when you want 2 way binding in child controller.

```
<select ng-change="refreshAmount()" ng-model="color.myColor" ng-options="color as color for color in colors">
  </select>     

 $scope.color ={  
     myColor: $scope.colors[2]
 };

 $scope.refreshAmount = function() {
     $scope.color.myColor = $scope.colors[0];
     $log.info($scope.color);
 }
```